# Why does "pydoc -g" at the command prompt bring up python libraries installed on my system, but I can't do that command from the Python Interpreter?

Tags: python, command-prompt, iterm, pydoc

Why does typing:

```
  [user_name]$ pydoc -g
```

in iTerm (the command prompt) bring up the python index of modules on my computer, but I can't run that line from the Python Interpreter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pydoc is a command line program `/usr/bin/pydoc`. In the Python Interpreter you can only access python classes and modules.

If you want to do the same from the interpreter, you can import the `pydoc` module and then call `pydoc.gui()`.

Comment: Thanks man. Just to clarify, how is the 'pydoc' module related to the 'pydoc' command line program?

Comment: The pydoc command line program is a small python script. 

It imports pydoc and then calls pydoc.gui() :-)

Comment: cool! I see, so when I am in the interpreter and type 'import pydoc' and then 'pydoc.gui()' that's the same thing as calling the '$pydoc -g' script from the command line. If you don't mind my asking, what other python scripts are inherently available from the command line?

Comment: `pydoc` the program is a small driver program which imports `pydoc` (the module). Try `cat /usr/bin/pydoc2.6` to see the program (note that `/usr/bin/pydoc` itself may be a version-select script).

Answer (score 1):

Because Pydoc is not a call to some feature built into the Python standard library. Pydoc is an external program, that runs functions on Python code. It works on iTerm because iTerm can call such programs. For instance, you should be able to call programs like `cat`,  `grep` and `vim` from iTerm because it works with these external programs. But these are not available to Python through its interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen("pydoc -g", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()
```

The above will call OS executables

Comment: Thanks!  Out of curiosity, I use .exe files all the time, but what's a good description of what OS executables are?

Comment: that hard :) , I think I have used a wrong term/less generic term...The above command will cover all the files that execute on OS default shell.